# Connection Timeout in request with RestTemplate is not working correctly

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, resttemplate, connection-timeout

I am using RestTemplate to get data from an external service, and I would like to set timeout for the request as follow:

```
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(600000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(600000).setSocketTimeout(600000).build()).build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(600000);
        requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(600000);
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(600000);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + settings.getBase64EncodedAuthString());
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<BaseParameters> request = new HttpEntity<>(parameters, headers);

        ResponseEntity<MyResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://my-external-service.com/service1", HttpMethod.POST,
                    request, MyResponse.class);
```

Although I have set the timeout to 600000ms (10 minutes), sometime I still got the timeout exception from server after only 20s, and this is the exception that I got:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException -> I/O error on
>   POST request for
>   "https://my-external-service.com/service1":
>   Connect to my-external-service.com:443
>    failed: Connection timed out:
>   connect; nested exception is
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   my-external-service.com:443
>   failed: Connection timed out: connect

Does anyone have an idea whether I made here something wrong with the timeout configuration or do I need to configure something more? Thank you

Comment: can you check whether two different version of commons-httpclient jar is present. if present then remove one and try.

Comment: Hi, in the library I have: commons-httpclient-3.1, httpcore-4.4.6 and httpclient-4.5.3

Comment: add only one httpClient remove  commons-httpclient-3.1

Comment: Thank you, i will try to remove  commons-httpclient-3.1 and test it again

Comment: hi, I did try to remove the commons-httpclient-3.1 and leave only the httpclient-4.5.3 but the timeout exception is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177539/discussion-between-dhruv-raj-singh-and-schau).

Comment: any update on this. I have a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

You are using HTTP request configuration, Request level configuration applies only once the connection route has been fully established. It does not apply to SSL handshakes or CONNECT requests. You need to configure socket properties applied by the connection manager upon connection creation.

This link will be helpful https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11379

Comment: yeah I did set a new SocketConfig object in my httpClient as follow: HttpClients.custom().setDefaultSocketConfig(SocketConfig.custom().setSoTimeout(600000).build()).build() but it still did not work :(

Comment: Add setConnectionTimeout
because connection is not established
.setSoTimeout is the timeout for receiving the data when connection is established

Comment: yes as you can see from my codes above, I did set already the connectionTimeout as 600000ms in the HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory object